# How can I apply groupBy() to only create groups of more than X elements in Pyspark?

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, group-by, pyspark

I am trying to apply the groupBy() clause over a dataframe to group equal instances, but I want it to be applied only if there can be created groups of more than 3 elements. I mean, if I have 2 equal instances, I don't want to group them, but if I have more than 2 equal instances I want to create a group of them.

I am using this code to create the groups but I don't know how to change it to solve the problem I am facing:

```
dataframe_grouped = dataframe.groupBy(columns)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataframe for example

```
>>> a = [("foo",3),("foo",11),("foo",22),("bar",3),("foo",5)]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(a,["name","value"])
>>> df.show()
+----+-----+
|name|value|
+----+-----+
| foo|    3|
| foo|   11|
| foo|   22|
| bar|    3|
| foo|    5|
+----+-----+
```

Apply a filter on the number of occurence after your groupBy()

```
>>> df2 = df.groupBy(df.name).count().filter("count>3").show()
>>> df2.show()
+----+-----+
|name|count|
+----+-----+
| foo|    4|
+----+-----+
```

Then you can use elements of the column "name" of df2 and join them with the elements of the column "name" of df1.
So df3 will be a dataframe with only the elements that have equal instances higher than 3.

```
>>> df3 = df.join(df2, df.name == df2.name).select(df2.name, df.value)
>>> df3.show()
+----+-----+
|name|value|
+----+-----+
| foo|    3|
| foo|   11|
| foo|   22|
| foo|    5|
+----+-----+
```

If you work on df3 you can use groupBy() and you will have groupedData that will have more than 3 elements for each "name".

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing extract that columns by

```
 SeriesName = dataframe_grouped['column_name']
```

Now check the occurrence of that particular string in that series . Find the syntax from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html)

From the count you will get the number of sequence and those which have more than 2 , put those in a different series and then add that series in the dataframe.

```
dataframe_grouped['new_column'] = newSeries
```

and then perform a group by on that new column`dataframe.groupBy(new_column)`